# C# parse a line and extract all integers enclosed in "" in a given line

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am processing a file(could be a cs, xml or any)where i need to extract strings that are in format "123". Any number enclosed in "" could range from 1 to 10000.

Here is what i used but it does not return multiple matches
  
Expected output: "828", "9999"

My code:

```
var match = Regex.Match(line,"\"\\d*\"");

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    lstStringIds.Add(match.Value);                    
                }
```

My match always gives only one match. How do i get multiple matches of integers??

Comment: `"(?:\d{1,4}|10000)"`?

Comment: ty @heemayl but it still gives me one match

Comment: Are you getting one _match_, or one _digit_? If you only get one _match_ that is because you only tell it to get one. Use the `Regex.Matches()` method instead and iterate through that using a `foreach`-loop.

Comment: you are awesome i was getting only one. I was in assumption that regex was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Test it:

```
string myline = @"""123"" ""5587"" ""9"" ""7896""";

var resultlist = Regex.Matches(myline, @"\d+").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
```

Returns:

```
123 
5587 
9 
7896
```

For further information, please see: [Regex.Matches Method (String, String, RegexOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b49yw9s8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: this seems to work but it matches "1.0" which i dont want

Comment: You didn't mentioned that... And this should not return "1.0", because of pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Non-LINQ approach.

```
string line = "\"802\" and \"1009\" and \"1.0\" and \"10001\" and \"10000\"";
var lstStringIds = new List<String>();
var match = Regex.Match(line, "\"(?:\\d{1,4}|10000)\"");
while (match.Success)
{
    lstStringIds.Add(match.ToString());
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Returns:
"802"
"1009"
"10000"

Comment: Shamelessly stole the regex pattern from @heemayl.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int count = 0; count < input_string.Length; count ++)
{
    if ((input_string[count] == //first number) && (input_string[count + 1] == //second number) && (input_string[count + 2] == //third number))
    {
        lstStringIds.Add(input_count[count]);
        // [count + 1]
        // [count + 2]
    }
}
```

That's how I would cycle through a list to find substrings that are equal to a condition. Let me know if that wasn't helpful or wasn't what you were looking for.

Comment: I forgot to add those characters to a string so that the list would only have one input: string match = input_string[count] + input_string[count + 1] + input_string[count + 2]; LstStringIds.Add(match);

Answer (score 0):

```
    string line = "\"100\", \"200\" ";
    var match = Regex.Match(line, "(\"\\d*\")");
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    while(match.Success && match != null)
    {
        al.Add(match.Value);
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
```